# Why callback method in subscribe function in the root component fired when i move between diffrent pages in the app?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I use Angular 10 and I created this server that returns an observable:

```
export class CountrySelectionService {

 private _activeCountry = new BehaviorSubject(this.getCountries()[0]);

   public getActiveCountryPush(): Observable<CountrySpec> {
    return this._activeCountry.asObservable();
    }
    
  constructor(private utilService:UtilService){}

  getCountries(): CountrySpec[] {
    return  [new CountrySpec("assets/images/canadaFlag.svg", Country.CA, "sales@dwinfo.com"), 
             new CountrySpec("assets/images/usaFlag.svg", Country.US, "sales@dwinfo.com")]
  }

  setActiveCountry(countrySpec: CountrySpec): void {
    this._activeCountry.next(countrySpec);
  } 
}
```

In app.component.ts(root component) file in ngOnInit function I  use above method:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

  this.countrySelectionService.getActiveCountryPush().subscribe({
    x=> { someFoo(x.name) }
  });
}
```

I expect that someFoo callback method will be fired only when _activeCountry property is updated.
But actually, someFoo callback method is fired not only when _activeCountry property is updated but also fired when I move to another page of the app.

Any idea why someFoo method fired not only when _activeCountry property is updated?
And how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz demo reproducing this problem? If you subscribe in your root component then this should not be happening I think.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure callback is fire only in component you should unsubscribe when component is destroyed by adding ngOnDestroy event.

```
subscriptions: Subscription[];

ngOnInit(): void {

  let sub = this.countrySelectionService.getActiveCountryPush().subscribe({
    x=> { someFoo(x.name) }
  });
  this.subscriptions.push(sub);
}

ngOnDestroy() {    
    this.subscriptions.forEach((sub) => {
      sub.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Agreed, the problem is the subscription is not unsubscribed. Hence, this problem.

Comment: But app.component.ts is the root component, as I understand the root component is destroyed only when the app is closed... so it will not do the job

Comment: Does your app only have one root component? In case it have many component, it will be init and destroy as normal. You can add log ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy to see what happen.